# Regex in R to match a group of words and split by space

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Split the regex by space if the group of words is not matched. 
If group of words is matched then keep them as it is.

```
text <-  c('considerate and helpful','not bad at all','this is helpful') 
pattern <- c('considerate and helpful','not bad')
```

Output :
considerate and helpful, not bad, at, all, this, is, helpful

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should supply an attempt at a solution or explain specifically what you are confused about.

Comment: `pattern <- c(considerate, not)
regex_or       <- paste(pattern, collapse="|")
split_regex    <- regex(paste("((?<!",regex_or,"))\\s"))
str_split(text, split_regex)`   this helps if im looking for one word patterns, but i am looking for an expression that can take more than one word as pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, just put the words in front of `\w+`:

```
library("stringr")
text <-  c('considerate and helpful','not bad at all','this is helpful') 
parts <- str_extract_all(text, "considerate and helpful|not bad|\\w+")
parts
```

Which yields

```
[[1]]
[1] "considerate and helpful"

[[2]]
[1] "not bad" "at"      "all"    

[[3]]
[1] "this"    "is"      "helpful"
```

It does not split on whitespaces but rather extracts the "words".